# Show Div based on default radio button selected using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form based on two radio buttons. I want to show a DIV if one radio button is selected on page load. If value 'YES' is saved on form then on each page load the DIV should be shown. If no value is saved on form then the DIV should not be visible.

P.S. I have implemented the functionality on DIV show and hide on radio button selection only with Javascript.

Here is my code:- first section of page.

```
                    <script>
                    function yesnoinsCheck() {
                        if (document.getElementById('yesinsCheck').checked) {
                            document.getElementById('showexplain').style.display = 'block';
                            style.opacity = 0;
                            setTimeout(fade, 40);
                        }
                        else document.getElementById('showexplain').style.display = 'none';
                        style.opacity = 1;
                        setTimeout(fade, 40);
                    }

                </script>

<tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" class="had-insurance" onchange="javascript:yesnoinsCheck();" id="yesinsCheck" name="125" value="1" <?php if($detail_trailer['had_insurance_'] == '1') echo 'checked'?> checked=""><span class="radio-text">Yes</span>
                            <input type="radio" class="had-insurance" onchange="javascript:yesnoinsCheck();" id="noinsCheck" name="125" value="2" <?php if($detail_trailer['had_insurance_'] == '2') echo 'checked'?>><span class="radio-text">No</span>
                        </td> 
                    </tr>


                     <tr id="showexplain" style="display: none;"></tr>
```

section section of page:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('boxphysical').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('boxphysical').style.display = 'none';

}
</script>

<td>
                            <input type="radio" class="physical-damage" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" id="yesCheck" name="120" value="1" <?php if($detail_trailer['physical_damage_insurance'] == '1') echo 'checked'?> checked=""><span class="radio-text">Yes</span>
                            <input type="radio" class="physical-damage" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" id="noCheck" name="120" value="2" <?php if($detail_trailer['physical_damage_insurance'] == '2') echo 'checked'?>><span class="radio-text">No</span>
                        </td> 
  <tr id="boxphysical" style="display:none;" ></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:**EDITED**

```
       <script>
      function atLoadTime(){
      if (document.getElementById('yesinsCheck').checked) {
          document.getElementById('showexplain').style.display = 'block';
      }

      if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
          document.getElementById('boxphysical').style.display = 'block';
      }
      }
                    function yesnoinsCheck() {
                        if (document.getElementById('yesinsCheck').checked) {
                            document.getElementById('showexplain').style.display = 'block';
                           // style.opacity = 0;
                            //setTimeout(fade, 40);
                        }
                        else document.getElementById('showexplain').style.display = 'none';
                       // style.opacity = 1;
                        //setTimeout(fade, 40);
                    }


                    function yesnoCheck() {
                        if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
                            document.getElementById('boxphysical').style.display = 'block';
                           // style.opacity = 0;
                            //setTimeout(fade, 40);
                        }
                        else document.getElementById('boxphysical').style.display = 'none';
                       // style.opacity = 1;
                        //setTimeout(fade, 40);
                    }

                </script>
<body onload="javascript:atLoadTime();">


                            <input type="radio" class="had-insurance" onchange="javascript:yesnoinsCheck();" id="yesinsCheck" name="125" value="1" <?php if($detail_trailer['had_insurance_'] == '1')echo 'checked'?> ><span class="radio-text">Yes</span>
                            <input type="radio" class="had-insurance" onchange="javascript:yesnoinsCheck();" id="noinsCheck" name="125" value="2" <?php if($detail_trailer['had_insurance_'] == '2') echo 'checked'?>><span class="radio-text">No</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="physical-damage" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" id="yesCheck" name="120" value="1" <?php if($detail_trailer['physical_damage_insurance'] == '1') echo 'checked'?>><span class="radio-text">Yes</span>
                            <input type="radio" class="physical-damage" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" id="noCheck" name="120" value="2" <?php if($detail_trailer['physical_damage_insurance'] == '2') echo 'checked'?>><span class="radio-text">No</span>



                     <div id="showexplain" style="display: none;">hello there</div>

                      <div id="boxphysical" style="display: none;">second div............</div>
                     </body>
```

this should solve your problem.if you are using tr the first create table tag.

Comment: yes it's working fine but one more problem i have two different set of radio option section.so it works on one section not on other section on same page.

Comment: add those radio button also to you question.

Comment: Sorry i m new in stack flow that's y i have put code on wrong place

Comment: I have one header for all files so it would be good if onload is not call in body.

Comment: i have updated the answer.you would have done this addition by your own.any ways no problem.

Comment: then add it in your header.

Comment: Okay thanks working fine . I was added same just added else in function .that's y was not working fine